# Swagger with Spring Rest : api-docs does not generate the json

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I am trying to integrate swagger2 with my Spring MVC. But when I try to access http://myhost/myapp/api-docs, I am not able to get the json. Could you please help me to figure out whats going wrong with my code.

**My Pom.xml (swagger related)**

```
<dependency> 
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> 
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId> 
      <version>2.2.2</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> 
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId> 
      <version>2.2.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

**My web.xml**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**My mvc-dispatcher.xml**

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.smith.spring.ws" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.smith.spring.swagger" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html" mapping="swagger-ui.html" /> 
    <mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" mapping="/webjars/**" />
```

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
public class SwaggerConfig{  
    @Autowired  
    @Bean  
    public Docket api(){  
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
            .select()  
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())  
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())  
            .build()  
            .groupName("person")
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());                
    }  
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "My Project's REST API", 
                "This is a description of your API.", 
                "API TOS",
                "url",
                "me@wherever.com", 
                "API License", 
                "API License URL");
        return apiInfo;
    }      
}
```

**My Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
@Api(value="Person Rest Service")
public class PersonController {
 @RequestMapping(value="/getPerson",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 @ApiOperation(value = "Fetch a person")
 public @ResponseBody Person getPersons() {
  Person person = new Person();
  person.setFirstname("fname");
  person.setLastname("lname");
  person.setAge(37);
  person.setDepartment("dept");
  return person;
 }
}
```

I am not sure if I am missing anything here. But when I try to access http://localhost:8080/MyApp/api-docs, I am not able to see the json.

I would be really grateful if someone can throw light on this.

Thanks,Smith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct url is  http://localhost:8080/MyApp/v2/api-docs

You can also access swagger ui http://localhost:8080/MyApp/swagger-ui.html

Use `@EnableSwagger2` annotation on top of your `SwaggerConfig` class.

In your `mvc-dispatcher.xml` file add `<bean name="swaggerConfig" class="com.smith.spring.swagger.SwaggerConfig"/>`

Also not sure if necessary but change `<mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html" mapping="swagger-ui.html" />` to `<mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" mapping="swagger-ui.html" />`

Comment: When i try to access with v2/api-docs, i still not getting the json. Same with directly accessing swagger-ui.html

Comment: Thanks it worked. I am able to access the swagger ui thru link http://localhost:8080/MyApp/swagger-ui.html and get all details. But still http://localhost:8080/MyApp/v2/api-docs is not giving any output.

Comment: Also be sure to update the springfox dependency to 2.4.0 (not 2.2.2)